# Evaluate a derivative by definition

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

Consider the following function, where $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}\in C^1$:

$$g(x,y) = y\cdot f(x^2-y^2)$$

So the partial derivative for $x$:

$$g_x(x,y) = 2xyf'(x^2 - y^2)$$

Now, I want to get the same result using the definition:

$$g_x(x,y) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{g(x+h, y) - g(x,y)}{h} = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{yf((x+h)^2 - y^2) - yf(x^2-y^2)}{h} =\\ y\cdot \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f((x+h)^2 - y^2) - f(x^2 - y^2)}{h}$$

How do I proceed?

Comment: I think you will need the definition of / equation for the function $f$.  Without this information, I highly doubt if you would be able to compute for the partial derivative of $g_x(x,y)$, using the limit definition.

Comment: $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$, but you put $x^2-y^2$ as an argument. So either the definition is wrong or $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^2$?